# Socket-connection: How does one end know that the other end received the message?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple socket client-server application. If the client makes a request to the server via a socket-connection, how does it know, that the server received the message, when the acknowledgement gets lost? I'm struggling with the following scenario:

The server receives a client requests and starts processing the message. Server sends an acknowledgement to the client which may never reach the client. The client thinks that the message was not received by the server. In this case I want to prevent that the client sends the request again to the server, as latter may already have triggered processes that are only allowed to be triggered once per request.

Comment: Why did the client give up on the first request just because it didn't receive a response from the server? It still needs to know whether the request was processed, right? And the server knows, right?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because it may block the thread waiting for a response which may never come (e.g. server didn't get the request)

Comment: Blocking indefinitely would just be poor design. If the client does something that foolish, the client should be fixed to not give up on the first request just because the server doesn't reply but to instead take more appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response (or ack) from the server got lost, then the client will not know if the server received and processed the request or not. In some cases it is not a problem that a request was processed twice, in other cases it is.

The common way to solve this is not to check in the client if a request was successfully received by the server, but to detect duplicate requests at the server and ignore these. For this the request needs to have some sufficiently unique identifier, like a simple request counter, transaction id or similar. Or the server might treat the request itself as a unique id, i.e. will detect if exactly the same content was sent twice.

The best implementation depends on the actual use case. But for example protocols like TCP or RTP have some increasing sequence number so that the server just needs to remember the last process number in order to detects duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Steffen! I also though about queuing the responses at server side so that clients can request their response, kind of ask for the status. But I guess that will lead to too much network overhead?
So, if re-requesting on client-side is the default procedure after timeouts, what's an acknowledge worth then?

Comment: @cobby: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. A retransmit is triggered after a timeout if an ack got not received. A retransmit will happen as long as no ack was received. So an ack is still needed. But the server should not process the same request twice, that's why it needs to detect if a request is the same.

Comment: I see, I was thinking in the context of specific response in addition to the acknowledgement, e.g. a text message. I guess the server has to store the response temporarily and discard it if it doesn't receive the same request again. If it does the same request again, it simple responds with the stored response from the early request.